# Issue connecting to database - php

Tags: php, html, database

I am trying to upload an image of a plane and then the user needs to fill the registration, airport, and company and then upload it, the problem is that the information is not going to the database, any suggestion?

```
<?php
include("connection.php");
?>

<html>
<body>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    Matricula:  <input type="text" name="registration" value=""/><br><br>
    Aeroporto:  <input type="text" name="airport" value=""/><br><br>
    Companhia:  <input type="text" name="company" value=""/><br><br>

    Upload da foto: <input type="file" name="uploadfile" value=""/><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>

</form>

<?php

if ($_POST['submit']) 

{
    $mat = $_POST["registration"];
    $air = $_POST["airport"];
    $comp = $_POST["company"];
    $filename = $_FILES["uploadfile"]["name"];
    $tempname = $_FILES["uploadfile"]["tmp_name"];
    $folder = "fotos/".$filename;
    move_uploaded_file($tempname, $folder);


    if($mat!="" && $air!="" && $comp!="" && $filename!="") 
    {
        $query = "INSERT INTO aviacao VALUES 
 ('$mat','$air','$comp','$folder')";
        $data = mysql_query($conn, $query);


    if($data) 
    {

        echo "Foto inserida na Base de Dados";
    }       


    }
    else
    {
        echo "Preencher todos os campos";
    }
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

**Database**

1. 1   matricula   varchar(35)
2. 2   aeroporto   varchar(100)
3. 3   companhia   varchar(100)
4. 4 foto  varchar(100) (here should go the path    to the folder where
   the photos are beign stored)

Comment: Please note that the `mysql_*` functions have been **deprecated since 2013** (in PHP 5.5), and are **removed as of PHP 7** (released in 2015). This is because they have **serious** security vulnerabilities. **DO NOT USE THEM**. Please consider switching to either [**MySQLi**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead, ensuring that you also use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) :)

Comment: You probably are using the wrong function. `mysql_query` should be `mysqli_query` assuming `$conn` is a `mysqli` connection. Add the connection.php if unsure. @ObsidianAge It looks like they just made a typo, that is the correct `mysqli` syntax for the `query` function.

Comment: You should use parameterized queries though, to (as previously mentioned) prevent injections.

Comment: What's in connection.php, also show us your error messages.

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for the anwers, i add the "i" in the ($data = mysqli_query($conn, $query); and it worked the data is stored in the database...but now it appears an error "Notice: Undefined index: submit in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-www\indio\insert.php on line 21" but its not affecting the operation it seems....

Comment: here goes the connection.php : <?php
 //defenir variavel de ligacao ao servidor
 $servername="localhost";
 $username="root";
 $password="";
 $dbname="indio";
 //criar ligacao á BD
 $conn=mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);
 if ($conn->connect_error)
 {
  die("Erro na ligação:" .$conn->connect_error);
 }
?>